# Como puedo listar un grupo de datos en un solo campo en MySql

Tags: mysql

Saludos no puedo realizar una sintaxis que me liste la siguiente información en una misma columna por ello les pido de su ayuda no logro hacerlo.

La orden número 10248 fue enviada en Tuesday 16 de August del 1994
La orden número 10249 fue enviada en Wesnesday 10 de August del 1994
La orden número 10250 fue enviada en Friday 12 de August del 1994
La orden número 10251 fue enviada en Monday 15 de August del 1994
La orden número 10252 fue enviada en Thursday 11 de August del 1994
La orden número 10253 fue enviada en Tuesday 16 de August del 1994

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa función `concat()`:

```
select concat(campo1,campo2,campo3) from tuTabla
```

Pero le agregamos separación con coma y espacio por ejemplo:

```
select concat(campo1,", ",campo2,", ",campo3) from tuTabla
```

Y le ponemos un alias para que diga "Texto" por ej.

```
select concat(campo1,", ",campo2,", ",campo3)as Texto from tuTabla
```

O sea que en tu caso quedaría:

```
select concat("La orden número ",campo1," fue enviada en ",campo2)as Texto from tuTabla
```

Para mostrar la fecha en otro formato, por ej. este:

```
select concat("La orden número ",campo1," fue enviada en ",dayname(campoFecha)," ",dayofmontht(campoFecha)," de ",monthname(campoFecha)," del ",year(campoFecha))as "Histórico de envío" from tuTabla
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias los coloque de la siguiente forma:                                  
         select concat("La orden número",OrderID," fue enviada en 
                ",ShippedDate)as "Histórico de envío" 
                  from orders                                                                                                                                               .Sin embargo la fecha la trae de esta forma 1996-07-16 00:00:00' y la requiero poder listar así: Tuesday 16 de August del 1994                             como se podría realizar solo muestra

Comment: `select concat("La orden número ",OrderID," fue enviada en ",dayname(ShippedDate)," ",date_format(ShippedDate,'%d %M %Y'))as "Histórico de envío" from orders`

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo ejecute pero no me listo los valores, arroja valor null en el campo.

Comment: no puede ser, a mi me funciona. El tipo de fecha lo tengo en `datetime`, vos?

Comment: No Estimado, no me funciona.

Comment: entonces mostrá más información referida a la estructura de la base de datos, o de la tabla `orders ` por lo menos..si no va a ser imposible ayudarte. Tampoco me respondiste la pregunta: de que tipo es tu campo ShippedDate"

Comment: Estoy trabajando con la base de datos Northwind y la tabla es orders y el campo ShippedDate tiene en su interno la fecha estructurada de esta forma 1996-07-04 00:00:00

Comment: Mira también lo coloque este forma pero no me trae fecha: select concat("La orden número",OrderID," fue enviada en ")as "Historico de envío",
DATE_FORMAT(ShippedDate,'%d - %b - %Y') AS ShippedDate
from orders

Comment: fijate esta: `select concat("La orden número ",OrderID," fue enviada en ",dayname(ShippedDate)," ",date_format(ShippedDate,'%Y %M %d'))as "Histórico de envío" from orders`

Comment: De acuerdo Aprendiz, te pido disculpa si me cuesta un poco redactar mejor las consultas dado que estoy aprendiendo a manejar el MySql.

Comment: @Aprendiz no entiendo por qué me pusieron un voto negativo

Comment: @Aprendiz me molestó por que me tomé el trabajo de responder una pregunta no muy bien formulada y me ponen un voto negativo. Si fue maiker vasquez yo le recomiendo que agregue más info antes de votar, pero no pasa nada.. Saludo!

Comment: No fui yo estimado, no seria capaz mas bien agradecido a usted y a todos por el apoyo, Saludos.

Comment: A sido muy valiosa la ayuda revise la herramienta y coloque en positivo y en verde todas las opciones posibles que permite, ya que estoy muy agradecido por la atención y el tiempo tomado para ayudarme independientemente de que no termine el ejercicio.

Comment: pensé que habías sido vos, disculpa. Te sigue mostrando `null`? probaste con la última modificación que te pasé: cambiando esto `'%d %M %Y'` por esto `'%Y %M %d'`?

Comment: También se puede hacer de esta otra manera: `select concat("La orden número ",OrderID," fue enviada en ",dayname(ShippedDate)," ",dayofmontht(ShippedDate)," de ",monthname(ShippedDate)," del ",year(ShippedDate))as "Histórico de envío" from orders`

Comment: Descuida Estimado, listo ahora si funciona bien, mil gracias.